# What is equivalent of timer of C# in C++ using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to use a timer in my code. I m programming in C++ using Qt creator. Is there a way to emulate the timer in C++ using Qt that will trigger an event at a specific interval when enabled, similar to what we generally do in C#?

Comment: Can we access properties of it (i.e through property manager), the way we do in C#?

Comment: You can simply google it or see the documentation : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QTimer.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Qt` it is called `QTimer`. It is a bit different than `C#` because the way to use it is through [Signals and Slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html). Here is an example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = 0) :
        QObject(parent)
    {
        connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onTimeOut()));
    }

    void startJob()
    {
        timer.start(1000);
    }

public slots:
    void onTimeOut()
    {
        qDebug() << "Time out!";
    }

private:
    QTimer timer;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyClass c;
    c.startJob();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I recommend reading the `QTimer` documentation from the [Qt documentation page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/reference-overview.html) as well as the [getting started guides](http://qt-project.org/doc/); it is one of the best documented pieces of software you can find and I think you'll love it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the assistant. There is something called QTimer. That should solve the problem.